# Videos randomly turns completely gray

Tags: windows-8, vlc-media-player

I'm using Windows 8 and sometimes when I'm watching .avi file, the video turns completely grey. Then if I'm lucky, it goes back to normal a couple seconds later. I know it isn't the video's fault because the problem never occurs at the same place.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

FYI, I'm using the most up-to-date version of VLC media player.

Comment: It might be a graphics problem. Have you updated your graphics board's drivers? Does the problem exist in other media players?

Comment: My GPU is up to date and the problem only occurs when playing .avi files in VLC. It works perfectly well in Window Media Player

Comment: Have you tried downgrading VLC (or resetting your preferences, after a backup, of course)?

Comment: No i haven't but, i never touched anything in preferences anyway.
I did try downgrading VLC but the problem was still there.

Comment: Can you post the link to your VLC bug post? Can you add more information about your current computer?

Comment: Here you go but, there's more information here anyway : https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=114581

Comment: I wouldn't call it dead, you posted it today and almost no questions asked today there are answered; give the VLC guys some time.

Answer (score 9):

Try playing with the file caching setting.

Tools > Preferences > Show Settings: All (bottom left) > Input/Codecs > Advanced section > File Caching

I changed it from 300ms to 1000ms and it fixed the problem. I suspect the grey screen issue happens whenever VLC fails to get the video data from the drive fast enough (slow drive/other programs accessing it).

Comment: 1000ms may be the default now (`vlc-core-1:3.0.12-1.fc33.x86_64` installed from the Fedora repo).

Comment: Mine was already adjusted to 1000ms by default. I increased Disc Caching from 300ms to 1000ms and it helped a bit. Version: `3.0.18 Vetinari`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. It seemed like VLC was using too much CPU.
Solved it by installing the 64bit version of VLC. [vlc-2.2.1-win64.exe](http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.1/win64/vlc-2.2.1-win64.exe)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that playing a video in VLC that is being accessed by another program, uTorrent in my case, would cause multiple grey screens throughout the playback.

I either closed the program (uTorrent) that was accessing the video or stopped it from using it. I restarted the video and no more grey screens appeared.